# how can i run all webdriver.io spec files in single browser session?

Tags: session, webdriver-io

I'm using wdio to run tests. I reduced maxInstances to 1.But wdio logging indicates that it creates a new session before each spec file. How can i run all webdriver.io spec files in single browser session?Thank you in advance.

wdio.conf.js is:

```
exports.config = {
  specs: ['./test/specs/**/*.js'],
  maxInstances: 1,
  capabilities: [{
    maxInstances: 1,
    browserName: 'chrome',
  }],
  sync: true,
  logLevel: 'verbose',
  coloredLogs: true,
  screenshotPath: './errorShots/',
  baseUrl: process.env.ROOT_URL,
  waitforTimeout: 10000,
  connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
  connectionRetryCount: 3,
  services: ['chromedriver'],
  framework: 'mocha',
  reporters: ['dot', 'spec', 'allure'],
  mochaOpts: {
    ui: 'bdd',
    timeout: 99999999
  },
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this workaround. It actually works for me with webdriverio v4

- List all of your specs in a single file. You can take advantage of autocomplete feature of the IDE you are using, e.g.

  specs.js

  ```
  require('./test/specs/test1');
  require('./test/specs/test2');
  // etc.
  require('./test/specs/testN');
  ```
- In your wdio.conf.js file, list the above spec.js file as the only spec, i.e.

  wdio.conf.js

  ```
  exports.config = {
      specs: ['./test/specs/specs.js'],
      // etc.
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

WebdriverIO will run each test file in a different session. To run them all in the same session, you'd need to put all your tests in the same file.

If you're finding yourself needing to run all your tests in the same session, perhaps you should re-work your tests... Maybe use [WebdriverIO's "before" hook](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/master/examples/wdio.conf.js#L234) if you need to do a common set up, like logging in to a site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm looking for a solution for tests in various files. While I don't know how to use WebdriverIO's "before" hook to solve this problem, thanks I will try.